# How get request and response log from postman calls?

Tags: proxy, postman, har

I want to get the sequence of all requests and responses from manual testing flow in postman. How can I achieve this? I cannot see how this can be done in postman without exporting each request and reponse pair manually from a postman proxy session. I am able to save a postman proxy session as a collection but that does not save the responses. Any format would do but I would prefer JSON (HAR or something like that).

Comment: The postman console contains this information.

Comment: Thanks!

Good input but I need all information and this is a message I get: "Body is more than 10 KB and can only be viewed in editor."

Would have been good if all of that console output could have been written to a file.